# Different date(time) in db and application - 10 minutes

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have very strange problem. I am getting object from database and this object has different date in application - always 10 minutes. I totally don't understand what is happening here. I use Symfony2 and MySql (MariaDB). Below example (18:50 and 18:40):

[image]
[image]

Anyone some idea? Why f** 10 minutes, timezone makes difference in hours.. I am totally stupid. Thx for help.

Code:

```
$synch = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('LizukKiteBundle:Synchronization')->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->orderBy('s.id', 'desc')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;

    if ($synch) {
        $synch = $synch[0];
    } else {
        $synch = null;
    }
    dump($synch);die();
```

//EDIT:

I discovered that always only the last record is printing with wrong date - but why? I don't have any idea :/

If I get more object from db always only the last one is "broken". Maybe it helps someone?

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Above again only last record - I guess that problem is in code.. but it looks ok.

EDIT///

Ok, problem was resolved. I forget that I am getting the last object from this database table in my Listener, in onKernelRequest method too. And there I had basic error in 'clone' code :(

I had:

```
$maintenanceTime = clone $maintenanceTime; //cloning Synchronization object here
$maintenanceTime = $maintenanceTime->getDate();
$maintenanceTime->modify('+5 minutes');
```

Solution is:

```
$maintenanceTime = clone $maintenanceTime->getDate(); //clonning DateTime object
$maintenanceTime->modify('+5 minutes');
```

Dont ask me why that weak code was created.
Thx for help and wasting yours time.

Comment: What timezones do you have in: server os, php, mysql?
Must read: [timezones aren't differentiated by hours](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time)

Comment: What about the records in the db? Are there the dates correctly persisted?

Comment: Everything looks fine.. Always only last record is broken.. I guess that code getting records from db causes a problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem was resolved. I forget that I am getting the last object from this database table in my Listener, in onKernelRequest method too. And there I had basic error in 'clone' code :(

I had:

```
$maintenanceTime = clone $maintenanceTime; //cloning Synchronization object here
$maintenanceTime = $maintenanceTime->getDate();
$maintenanceTime->modify('+5 minutes');
```

Solution is:

```
$maintenanceTime = clone $maintenanceTime->getDate(); //clonning DateTime object
$maintenanceTime->modify('+5 minutes');
```

Dont ask me why that weak code was created. Thx for help and wasting yours time.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, yes, I had the same issue, but not in `PHP` nor `Symfony2` but with `Java`. It is rather general issue.

The problem for me was that we were running our app on `Java7` which does not support **microseconds** but only **milliseconds**. It would seem that your DB is tricking you into thinking that it holds value `2015-03-29 18:40:18`, however it does have something like `2015-03-29 18:40:18.123456`. Thus, when you try to parse your `datetime` string into `DateTime` object it adds up does last 3 digits to first 3 generating enough time shift, roughly 10 minutes (in my case, it was 12 minutes).

So, I guess, the solution would be to check how does you DB engine store the `DateTime`. Is it typical `datetime` type or something else?

Hope this sheds some light with onto the issue :)